# Impersonation options in AspnetBoilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to implement impersonation. I referred to the [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Abp-Session?searchKey=impersonate) and also referred to a similar question & response [here](https://gist.github.com/hikalkan/8862d9f7ae8b4874976d).

So I see two methods.

1) To do it the way Aspnet.zero implements. In this it seems that user gets logged out and login again with the impersonated tenant & user (gets redirected to the url).

2) Follow a simpler method as in [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Abp-Session?searchKey=impersonate):

```
    using (_session.Use(42, null))
    {
        var tenantId = _session.TenantId; //42
        var userId = _session.UserId; //null
    }
```

In my case If I follow 1st method, I will have to redirect the user to the tenant url (in the format of {subdomain}.mydomain.com) which I am not very keen on doing.

So, If I follow 2nd method can I impersonate in such a way that it will work on impersonated tenant & userid until I switch it off (say by pressing a button)? User scenerio;

1. Host user go to tenant list.
2. Click [impersonate] for a selected tenant from the grid (impersonate as tenant admin)
3. work as the tenant admin of selected tenant
4. Click [switch off] or similar button that always appear at the header if user is in impersonate mode.

Comment: Is this a yes/no question?

Comment: updated the question with more information